# Postgresql 11.16 equal comparison on varchar with two space characters not working anymore

Tags: postgresql

We're experiencing a weird behavior on our select statements since we've updated from postgres 11.12 to 11.16.

We are selecting rows using a WHERE condition on a pretty simple Varchar column. The value that were looking for in the condition does contain two consecutive SPACE characters, something like this: `WORD1  WORD2`.

Our query for finding the necessary data looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'WORD1  WORD2';`

While this query used to be working fine (and still does on our older test systems), right now it does not find the given entry in our productive environment. What seems to be working though is really wild:

```
-- LIKE with % after word working
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'WORD1  WORD2%';

-- LIKE with % before word working
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%WORD1  WORD2';

-- ILIKE without % working
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ILIKE 'WORD1  WORD2';

-- IS NOT DISTINCT FROM working
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'WORD1  WORD2';

-- standard equals (=) NOT working
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'WORD1  WORD2';
```

We double checked white space characters before and after the visible string, even updated the value with plain text again to make sure no strange non visible stuff is found in the value. Nothing worked. We also checked other entries inside of the same table with only a single space between words like `WORD1 WORD2` which somehow still seems to be working, so from our perspective it seems to have something to do with `equals` and two white spaces in the varchar.

We are accessing the database through DB visualizer, through a Java 8 driver and through psql shell, all with the same result that `equals` does not seem to find the required entry.

Any help is greatly appreciate, we're a little out if ideas right now.

Comment: Is there any chance that the underlying data in the table may have changed?

Comment: Is there an index on the `name` column? Did you recently get an update for your Linux operating system? Then maybe you are affected by [glibc changes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes)

Comment: the rows we're looking for were created about 2 years ago and have not changed every since. Although I'm not an expert in postgres database updates, I am pretty certain the data was not altered through the update process.

Comment: [Quote from the release notes for 11.14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11-14.html) "*Also, several bugs have been found that may have resulted in corrupted indexes, as explained in the next several changelog entries. If any of those cases apply to you, it's recommended to reindex possibly-affected indexes after updating.*"

Comment: ty for that hint, I'm going to have a look into that. The column seems to be an index and we upgrade the linux system with our postgresql update as well, so this seems to be checking out

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt Could you please post sample result here? or you can copy the name column value from the result that you get after SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'WORD1  WORD2%'; or any other working query to notepad to check the existence of any special character

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name reindexing seemed to be working out perfectly, the query is working again and provides the correct results. It looks like updating the linux system changed the way it searched through our index trees, which resulted in queries not finding some entries anymore. Ty so much. If you want you can put it into an answer text and I'll happily accept it right away.